# ExtJs 4.1 Reload treepanel's store with root parameter

Tags: extjs

my store is like this :

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        fields: ['id', 'text', 'leaf'],
        root: me.rootDada
    });
```

set text

```
 me.setNodeText(me.rootDada);
```

tree  is allready renderd and my goal is reload this like this

```
   reLoadTree: function() {
    var me = this;

    mydwr.rootDada(me.id, function (response) {

        if (response.isSuccess) {

            //me.removeAll();
            me.getRootNode().removeAll();
            me.setNodeText(response.source);
            me.getRootNode().appendChild(response.source);
            // me.store.load(response.source); 



        } else {
            Ext.Msg.alert('error');
        }
    });

}
```

i tried like this `me.store.load({
                      params: {
                        root: response.source
                      }
                    });`

but it does't work.
please halp me if you can

Answer (score 0):

I have answer :) 
there is code snippet

```
           `me.setNodeText(response.source);
            me.setRootNode(response.source);
            me.expandAll();`
```